# Perl, Assign regex match to scalar

Tags: regex, perl

There's an example snippet in [Mail::POP3Client](http://search.cpan.org/~sdowd/Mail-POP3Client-2.18/POP3Client.pm) in which theres a piece of syntax that I don't understand why or how it's working:

```
foreach ( $pop->Head( $i ) ) {
    /^(From|Subject):\s+/i and print $_, "\n";
}
```

The regex bit in particular. `$_` remains the same after that line but only the match is printed. 
An additional question; How could I assign the match of that regex  to a scalar of my own so I can use that instead of just print it?

Comment: The `$_` variable is implied and set or used in lots of places in Perl. The `foreach` loop there assigns the lines popped because there's no named variable to assign to instead. Matching without using `=~` similarly matches against `$_` and a naked `print` or `say` would output `$_`. The line could have been written `/^(From|Subject):\s+/i and say;` and have exactly the same effect. You can just treat it like any other variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually pretty tricky. What it's doing is making use of perl's short circuiting feature to make a conditional statement. it is the same as saying this.

```
if (/^(From|Subject):\s+/i) { 
    print $_;
}
```

It works because perl stops evaluating and statements after something evaluates to 0. and unless otherwise specified a regex in the form `/regex/` instead of `$somevar =~ /regex/` will apply the regex to the default variable, `$_`

you can store it like this

```
my $var;    
if (/^(From|Subject):\s+/i) { 
        $var = $_;
}
```

or you could use a capture group

```
/^((?:From|Subject):\s+)/i
```

which will store the whole thing into `$1`